# New to me Plant Questions

Tags: identification, plant-health, plant-care

Mornings folks! 
I inherited this plant from an office that was closing down.  I’m hoping someone can help identify the plant so that I can look into proper care.
It needs to be repotted for sure as it’s currently a leaning tower.
Thanks so much! [image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This plant looks like a *Dracaena fragrans* or corn plant in English. It is pretty neglected. I think the main problem with this plant is that it outgrew the container, and it needs a much bigger one with fresh potting soil. Be sure the container has good drainage, that is with holes in the bottom.

The Corn plant is further a pretty easy plant, you can forget to water it once in a while, and it can stand in a spot with indirect sunlight.

What you could do is to transplant it to a bigger container, and you could try to prune it a little (but if you don't mind the current state of the leaves, pruning is not necessary). [Here](https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/dracaena-corn-plant.html) some detailed care instructions found on the net.

In time this could become your favorite plant! Good luck.